# iOS trying to post location updates to a server

Tags: php, ios, coordinates, cllocationmanager, http-get

Within my application, I am trying to post the gps coordinates of a users position to a server for storage so that I can eventually design a map that displays all the users locations. I am using HTTP get and a custom PHP API to handle the data passing from app to db. The problem I have is, every time didUpdateLocations is called, I update the server. It works sometimes, but then sometimes my query string says there is an undefined variable and blank data is being posted int he db. Why is sometimes it undefined, and sometimes not? Also, is there a better way to handle the data passing? I was going to use ASIHTTPRequest but I am using ARC and so that is no help to me.

Code:

```
- (void)postLocationUpdateFor:(NSString *)deviceToken withDeviceID:(NSString*)deviceID  withLatitude:(NSString *)latitude andLongitude:(NSString *)longitude {

    NSString *apiURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:ServerApiURL2, deviceToken, deviceID, latitude, longitude];
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiURL]];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", strResult);

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"deviceToken"];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"Entered new Location with the coordinates Latitude: %@ Longitude: %@", latitude, longitude);

    [self postLocationUpdateFor:@"123" withDeviceID:deviceToken withLatitude:latitude andLongitude:longitude];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
didUpdateLocations
```

can be called when you actually lost your location: entered into an Elevator / building. That's why is sometimes empty.

I would check and validate that location values before I will send the server.

Comment: Alright will do, also, is the best way to convert them to strings or is there a better way?

Comment: it is a float as I remember and it counts the 5 digit after decimal. So I would format as string like "%1.5f" and I would send it to server, if is a new, validated value, or a custom value wich "means" "Location is lost" like "-200" or something like that. You can convert to int to by multiplying with 100000 and divide at server side with the same value, as how is for you easyer